# NTLM logins with clojure

Tags: unit-testing, clojure, ntlmv2

I want to unit test a web application from Clojure. The web application tested is hidden behind NTLM-login. Is there any simple way to use existing clojure http-clients to login with credentials?

[Clj-http](https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http) throws an exception when I try to access the site, I guess it would be possible to extend the nice clj-http to be able to login via NTLM, but is there an already available solution?

*Current workaround: The command Curl have an option to login with ntlm, so I can use that as a (slurp "http://...") of sorts by calling that program by the `clojure.java.shell` lib*

Comment: found a discussion thread, not sure still valid https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http/issues/409